# I want to find the word embedding using BERT for a single word in a sentence. Anyone has any idea how to do it?

Tags: python, nlp, bert-language-model

For example in the sentence: "Earth revolves around the sun and rotate around its own axis", I want to embed it with BERT word embeddings and find the embedding for "rotate" in this particular sentence. How to do it?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please check [how ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please do not use unnecessary tags!

Answer (score 1):

[flair](https://github.com/flairNLP/flair) has made this quite easy. First install the library using

```
!pip install flair
```

then using the below code you can get the embedding for every token in a sentence AKA context:

```
from flair.data import Sentence
s = Sentence('the dummy sentence to be embedded')

from flair.embeddings import BertEmbeddings
bert_embedding = BertEmbeddings()
bert_embedding.embed(s)

for token in s:
   print(token.embedding)
```